# Why Jersey refuses to marshal generic types?

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, marshalling

I have a base class generic with generic type property and several classes inheriting from it. Something like that:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends Number> { 
    @XmlAnyElement
    public T getId() { return id; }
    private T id ; // init for hibernate bug workaround 
.....
}

@XmlRootElement
public class A extends BaseClass<Integer> {
    private String name;
    private String error;
    private String url; 

    public String getError() { return error; }  
    public void setError(String error) { this.error = error; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
    public String getUrl() { return url; }
}
```

When Jersey tries to marshals it throws:

```
    javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
    - with linked exception:
   [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.Integer" as an        element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:318)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:172)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.JSONMarshallerImpl.marshal(JSONMarshallerImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONMarshaller.marshallToJSON(BaseJSONMarshaller.java:103)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONMarshaller.marshallToJSON(BaseJSONMarshaller.java:91)
    ......
```

I can't add XmlRootElement annotation to Integer, so what I supposed to do?

Comment: Is this on the server side or on the client? Can you show the resource/client code?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add `@XmlRootElement` annotation to your `BaseClass`.